# How to fix a Django view that is not returning an HttpResponse Object? (CS50 Project 1)

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, cs50

I am receiving the following error when submitting a form.

```
ValueError at /edit_entry/hi/
The view encyclopedia.views.edit_entry didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
```

Here is the views.py that is triggering the error.

```
def edit_entry(request, title):
   if request.method == "POST":
       form = NewEditEntryForm(request.POST)
       if form.is_valid():
           title = form.cleaned_data["title"]
           content = form.cleaned_data["content"]
           util.save_entry(title, content)
           return HttpResponseRedirect("/wiki/" + title)
   else:
       form = NewEditEntryForm()
       return render(request, "encyclopedia/edit_entry.html",{
       "form": NewEditEntryForm(),
       "title": title,
       "content": util.get_entry(title)
       })
```

What is the issue and how can I fix it?

(I also need help prepopulating the form with already existing data. I have tried using initial, but that has not worked. What is the best way to prepopulate the form with existing data?)

util.save_entry

```
def save_entry(title, content):
    """
    Saves an encyclopedia entry, given its title and Markdown
    content. If an existing entry with the same title already exists,
    it is replaced.
    """
    filename = f"entries/{title}.md"
    if default_storage.exists(filename):
        default_storage.delete(filename)
    default_storage.save(filename, ContentFile(content))
```

Comment: what should happen when the form isnt valid?

Comment: @Sayse, I want it to display the form again for the user to fill out. Should I use form.errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry, I thought that you have a model.

```py
# on util.py

def get_entry_content(title):
    filename = f"entries/{title}.md"
    return default_storage.open(filename).read()

# on views.py
def edit_entry(request, title):
   if request.method == "POST":
       form = NewEditEntryForm(request.POST)
       if form.is_valid():
           title = form.cleaned_data["title"]
           content = form.cleaned_data["content"]
           util.save_entry(title, content)
           return HttpResponseRedirect("/wiki/" + instance.title)
   else:
       content = util.get_entry_content(title)
       initial_dict = {
           "title" : title,
           "content" : content,
       }
       form = NewEditEntryForm(initial=initial_dict)
   return render(request, "encyclopedia/edit_entry.html", {
       "form": form,
   })
```

All right, I think if this is not doing what you want, i would test the `save_entry` function in the console, creating and updating to see if it works or not.

Comment: your solution worked (thank you!), but my form is not saving the edits (it should be doing so with `util.save_entry(title, content)`) or redirecting the user to the wiki page (done with `return HttpResponseRedirect("/wiki/" + title)`). Do you know what I should do  to fix this problem?

Comment: ups, it is an edit, i didn't realized, i'll update my answer

Comment: in the `entry = get_object_or_404(Entry, title=title)` I am receiving an error message that `name 'Entry' is not defined`. Looking online told me that the first argument should be a Django model, but I have not created a Django model in my code. How do I fix this error?

Comment: show me your `util.save_entry` implementation please

Comment: I added the util.save_entry.

Comment: thank you! I was able to make it work. I also need to prepopulate the form with the existing data that is in the entry. Would you be able to help me do that?

Comment: updated, something like that should works!

Comment: this works (thank you so much!), but the text inside the edit box starts with b and is surrounded in single quotation marks. Ex: `b'A word that is used as a greeting.'`  If you save the entry again, the quotations and b are added to the entry. Is there any way to remove this?

Comment: try with `return default_storage.open(filename, mode='r').read()` or `return str(default_storage.open(filename).read())`